# How to detect the way Bootstrap modal is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm attaching handler to the Bootstrap `hidden.bs.modal` event to detect when the modal is closed, but it can be closed in multiple ways:

1. Explicitly close it via`$('#modal').modal('hide')` or `$('#modal').modal('toggle')`;
2. Clicking on modal's backdrop part (if allowed);
3. Via data attributes e.g. `data-dismiss="modal"`

Is there a way to detect which of the options was used? Inside the `hidden.bs.modal` handler `e.target` always appears to be `div#modal`

Comment: As far as I know, no.  But I think a more import question is - why does it matter?

Comment: @LeroStav If you have a dialog where some user input is required, you need to know how the user closed it. You wouldn't want to act on user input from a dialog that was canceled.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The thing is that `hidden.bs.modal` is an event that fires once the modal has been closed. So that is not the `click` event the user triggered from the close button, the corner X or the overlay...

That said, you can use the `click` event to store where the user clicked in a variable **and** milliseconds after, when the `hidden.bs.modal` fires, use the variable.

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Variable to be set on click on the modal... Then used when the modal hidden event fires
  var modalClosingMethod = "Programmatically";

  // On modal click, determine where the click occurs and set the variable accordingly
  $('#exampleModal').on('click', function (e) {

    if ($(e.target).parent().attr("data-dismiss")){
      modalClosingMethod = "by Corner X";
    }
    else if ($(e.target).hasClass("btn-secondary")){
      modalClosingMethod = "by Close Button";
    }
    else{
      modalClosingMethod = "by Background Overlay";
    }

    // Restore the variable "default" value
    setTimeout(function(){
      modalClosingMethod = "Programmatically";
    },500);
  });

  // Modal hidden event fired
  $('#exampleModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    console.log("Modal closed "+modalClosingMethod);
  });

  // Closing programmatically example
  $('#exampleModal').modal("show");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#exampleModal').modal("hide");
  },1000);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/bzbVEd?editors=1011)

Comment: I loved this answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hide.bs.modal` event to capture the `document.activeElement`. If you have multiple buttons all of which include `data-bs-dismiss='modal'`, this will allow you to determine which of those buttons was pressed. This avoids the need for `onclick=` approaches or additional event handlers.

It seems it would be more elegant if the `Event` object for the `hide.bs.modal` event had a `.relatedTarget` or similar which contained the triggering element, but alas that's not the case right now.

The example below assumes jQuery with `$`:

```js
$(() => {
    var $dlg = $("#myBootstrapModalDialog");
    var $closeElement;

    $dlg.on('show.bs.modal', (e) => {
        // maybe do something to initialize the modal here...
    })
    .on('hide.bs.modal', (e) => {
        $closeElement = $(document.activeElement);
    })
    .on('hidden.bs.modal', (e) => {
        var id = $closeElement.attr('id');
        // do something depending on the id...
        if (id === 'btn-save') {
            // save something
        }
        $closeElement = null;
    });
});
```

Sample HTML:

```html
<div class="modal fade"
     id="myBootstrapModalDialog"
     tabindex="-1"
     aria-labelledby="myDialogTitle"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content rounded-0 mx-auto">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title text-primary" id="myDialogTitle">
                    Save this stuff?
                </h3>
                <button id="btn-close" type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body px-3">
                Are you sure you want to save this stuff?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="btn-cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                    Cancel
                </button>
                <button id="btn-save" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```