# Capture event on modal close

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am having a problem. I have the following code in HTML:

```
<a id="accessGeneral" class="simple-modal-atajos botonmas" style="cursor:pointer;"><div class="divbotonmas"><i class="fa fa-plus font18"></i></div></a>

<div class="simple-modal-atajos-content modal-content rounded-modal" style="padding:10px">

</div>
```

To show the modal I use:

```
$(document).on("click", ".simple-modal-atajos", function(evt) {
    $('.simple-modal-atajos-content').modal();
});
```

And now I want to capture the event when closing the modal by clicking outside of it, but I am not able to. I have tried these variants:

```
$(document).on("hidden", ".simple-modal-atajos-content", function () {
    alert('se cerro');
});

$(document).on("hide", ".simple-modal-atajos-content", function () {
    alert('se cerro');
});

$(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", ".simple-modal-atajos-content", function () {
    alert('se cerro');
});
```

But none seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54282019/how-to-detect-the-way-bootstrap-modal-is-closed/54291969#54291969

Comment: catching the event `hidden.bs.modal` should work, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ba1236mj/). Maybe are you getting a conflict with other javascript code which you didn't post?